# null is not an object (evaluating '_this.drawer._root') using native base Drawer

Tags: android, react-native, expo, native-base

I using the native-base library to create my app user interface, I make the native-base drawer and it's work correctly but when I move between component it gets an error for example when I move from Home screen to details screen and return to Home screen it gets an error like this `null is not an object (evaluating '_this.drawer._root')` from my details screen

Home.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Spinner, Icon, Left, Right, Button, Body, Title, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import Product from './components/Product';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar';

function HomeScreen({ navigation, props }) {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://boho-box.com/api/app')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };

  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#8498a3' }}
        androidStatusBarColor="#8498a3"
      >
        <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
            <Title style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >Products</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() => {
                this.openDrawer()
              }}
            >
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <Drawer
        side='right'
        ref={(ref) => {  this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar />}
      >
      <Content>
      {isLoading ?
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 24 }}>
          <Spinner color='#8498a3' />
        </View>
        :
        <ScrollView
              style={{
                flexGrow: 0,
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}>
              {
                data.map((product, index) => {
                  return(
                      <View style={styles.row} key={index}>
                        <View style={styles.col}>
                          <Product product={product}/>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                  )
                })
              }
        </ScrollView>
      }
      </Content>
      </Drawer>
    </Container>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  col: {
      flex: 1,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Details.js file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Spinner, Left, Right, Button, Body, Title, Icon, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import Item from './components/Item';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar';

function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation, props }) {

  const { name, price, img, text, productId } = route.params;

  const detail = {
    title: name,
    price: price,
    img:   img,
    text:  text,
    id: productId,
  }

  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };

  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#8498a3' }}
        androidStatusBarColor="#8498a3"
      >
        <Left>
          <Button transparent

            onPress={() => {
              navigation.goBack();
            }}
          >
            <Icon name='arrow-back' />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
            <Title style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >Products</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
            <Button transparent
            onPress={() => {
              this.openDrawer()
            }}
            >
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <Drawer
        side='right'
        ref={(ref) => {  this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar />}
      >
      <Content>
        <ScrollView>
          <Item pDetail={detail} />
        </ScrollView>
      </Content>
      </Drawer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default DetailsScreen;
```

Error screenshot when I want to return to Home screen:

[image]

I think the Home screen it's not rerender

react-native version: 0.63.2

native-base  version: 2.15.2

react-native-cli version: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You are using a functional component, so you should use the 'useRef' hook for this

```
const drawer = useRef(null);

<Drawer
        side='right'
        ref={drawer}
        content={<SideBar />}
      >
```

The function should be like below

```
openDrawer = () => {
    drawer.current._root.open()
  };
```

Comment: should I import `useRef` from react?

Comment: I do this but still, get that error but it changed to `null not an object (evaluating 'drawer.current._root')`

Comment: can i know where you are calling the openDrawer from ? this.openDrawer wont work in functional components

Comment: Inside the screen functions such as `HomeScreen` and `DetailsScreen` after `const drawer = useRef(null);`

Comment: yes the code is in   onPress={() => {
                this.openDrawer()
              }} is that correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231870/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-amir-hossein).